# Facing issue with csv.DictReader() while storing value to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I'm Trying to Read a csv using csv.DictReader() and storing the data which is in form of Dictionary to a list. But the Problem is The dict is not getting Generated correctly.

```
with open(report_object_items_filepath, 'r',encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        #load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)

        #convert each csv row into python dict
        for row in csvReader:
            #adding (row):python dict to json array
            jsonArray.append(row)
```

Output I'm getting -

```
{'FILE_ID;DASHBOARD_TITLE;OBJECT_TITLE;OBJECT_TYPE;LISTEN_TO_FILTER;ITEM_NAME;COLUMN_ORDER;OBJECT_ROW;OBJECT_COLUMN;OBJECT_WIDTH;OBJECT_HEIGHT;DATA_ITEM_FEATURES;SORT_ITEM_YN;REFERENCE_TREND_LINE;ITEM_CONDITION;AGGREGATION;DIMENSION_GROUP': 'TDSfile3;Dashboard 1;Sheet 1;;Gender;AdventureWorks_Customers.AnnualIncome;1;50000;30778;52422;24500;measure;;;;Sum;'}
```

Here in Output, It should contain the Dictionary keys separate and same for values. But Instead its in form of single string.

The Correct Result Should be keys be Individual holding values of there own.
As -

```
{'FILE_ID': 'TDSfile3', 'DASHBOARD_TITLE': 'Dashboard 1', 'OBJECT_TITLE': 'Sheet 1', 'OBJECT_TYPE': '', 'LISTEN_TO_FILTER': 'Gender', 'ITEM_NAME': 'AdventureWorks_Customers.AnnualIncome', 'COLUMN_ORDER': '1.0', 'OBJECT_ROW': '50000', 'OBJECT_COLUMN': '30778', 'OBJECT_WIDTH': '52422', 'OBJECT_HEIGHT': '24500', 'DATA_ITEM_FEATURES': 'measure', 'SORT_ITEM_YN': '', 'REFERENCE_TREND_LINE': '', 'ITEM_CONDITION': '', 'AGGREGATION': 'Sum', 'DIMENSION_GROUP': ''}
```

Comment: Try to fine-tune the `DictReader` by adding format arguments when creating it. `delimiter=';'` should help.

Answer (score 2):

it seems like your file in not really "comma separated" but semi-colon separated.  use `csv.DictReader(csvf, delimiter=';')`.

```py
from pprint import pp
import csv

csv_file = """\
FILE_ID;DASHBOARD_TITLE;OBJECT_TITLE;OBJECT_TYPE;LISTEN_TO_FILTER;ITEM_NAME;COLUMN_ORDER;OBJECT_ROW;OBJECT_COLUMN;OBJECT_WIDTH;OBJECT_HEIGHT;DATA_ITEM_FEATURES;SORT_ITEM_YN;REFERENCE_TREND_LINE;ITEM_CONDITION;AGGREGATION;DIMENSION_GROUP
TDSfile3;Dashboard 1;Sheet 1;;Gender;AdventureWorks_Customers.AnnualIncome;1;50000;30778;52422;24500;measure;;;;Sum;"""

data = list(csv.DictReader(csv_file.splitlines(), delimiter=';'))
pp(data)
```

output:

```json
[{'FILE_ID': 'TDSfile3',
  'DASHBOARD_TITLE': 'Dashboard 1',
  'OBJECT_TITLE': 'Sheet 1',
  'OBJECT_TYPE': '',
  'LISTEN_TO_FILTER': 'Gender',
  'ITEM_NAME': 'AdventureWorks_Customers.AnnualIncome',
  'COLUMN_ORDER': '1',
  'OBJECT_ROW': '50000',
  'OBJECT_COLUMN': '30778',
  'OBJECT_WIDTH': '52422',
  'OBJECT_HEIGHT': '24500',
  'DATA_ITEM_FEATURES': 'measure',
  'SORT_ITEM_YN': '',
  'REFERENCE_TREND_LINE': '',
  'ITEM_CONDITION': '',
  'AGGREGATION': 'Sum',
  'DIMENSION_GROUP': ''}]
```